# std::set_difference on list container

Tags: c++, list, stl, set-difference

I'm trying to call the set_difference function, and put the result on a std::list. In theory, it is possible to do this on any sorted container, right?

```
list<int> v;         

list<int> l1;  
list<int> l2;                   

list<int>::iterator it;

//l1 and l2 are filled here

l1.sort();
l2.sort();

it=set_difference(
   l1.begin(),
   l1.end(), 
   l2.begin(),
   l2.end(), 
   v.begin()
);
```

v is returning as an empty list, however. Is it because I can't use it on the list container?

Comment: I realized it=set_difference(...) was giving me problems too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because `v.begin()` is the beginning of an empty sequence. The elements get copied to pretty much anywhere. Replace it with `std::back_inserter(v)`. That will give you an iterator that knows how to insert into `v`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had another problem: I am doing it=set_difference(...) and it was giving me a compilation error. Fixing that + adding your function did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

You need to supply an output iterator that will *insert*. Try using [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter).

```
std::list<int> a { 
  10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13
};
std::list<int> b {
  10
};
std::list<int> diff;
std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
    std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
```

Comment: I will try your method later. The one posted by Pete Becker worked though. Is it possible to accept two answers here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @meOnomNom no, it's okay; just glad you figured it out :-)